# Database project with a lot of references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, reference, database-project

I just try to set up a database project in Visual Studio 2010. We have one database, that contains a lot of stored procedures. Unfortunately those procedures accesses quite a lot of other databases (30+), so I get a lot of "unresolved references" errors.

At the moment I see two possibilities to solve my problem:

- Add database projects to my solution, till I have all the errors resolved.
- Create a lot of schemas for all my databases and add them as reference.

Both possibilities are a lot of work, especially as there can come a lot more databases in the future. My dream would be, that I can just add the whole server as a reference. Is that possible somehow? Are there any other solutions I don't know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you. I found a article about referring databases [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386242.aspx) and this explains how to add multiple database project [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dukek/archive/2010/01/04/implementing-a-database-design-using-multiple-database-projects.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, looks like a helpful article.

Comment: It look like you could add the connection as a variable and then use that variable in views, storeprocedure and functions

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but you could setup one database to carry the references to the other databases via. "Server Objects -> Linked Servers" and change the code for the sp's to run through the 4 name quantifiers.

This would give you the added benefit of having the databases you depend on not hard coded.

Hope this is usefull to you.

Comment: Nope, can't change anything on the databases or the procedures.